# Code to intecept api calls to internal resources

Tags: javascript, interceptor

I wrote the below code to intercept all the http requests in my application. But, The below code only intercepts calls to external apis, but not api calls to internal resources. Can some one tell me what change I need to make inorder for my code to intercept api calls to internal resources like assets/1.json

```
   window.open = async (...args) => {
     let [resource, config] = args;

     if (resource.indexOf('://') === -1) {
       // request interceptor starts
       resource = resource + $('body').find('script:eq(0)').attr('src').split('//')[0] + '//' +
        $('body').find('script:eq(0)').attr('src').split('//')[1].split('/')[0];
       // request interceptor ends

     }

     const response = await originalOpen(resource, config);

     // response interceptor here
     return response;
   };
```

Thank you in advance